# How can we define a default configuration for xfce4-settings/display?

Tags: xfce, display-settings, display-manager

As in Cinnamon's display manager, I want to make last settings applied for connected display in XFCE4, but [XFCE4's display manager](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/display) asks for configuration (rotation, position etc.) everytime.

How can I make the last settings applied for a connected display in XFCE4?